# look for entry in html file and replace value in next line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a html file below is snippet from the file.

```
<tr>
  <th width='25%'><div class="detail"><b>VM Capacity</b></div></th>
  <td width='75%'>455</td>
  </tr>
```

Trying to edit the file using sed to change the value from 455 to 64. Using the below command.

```
sed -i '/<th width='25%'><div class="detail"><b>VM Capacity<\/b><\/div><\/th>/!b;n;c<td width='75%'>64</td>/g' cluster_report.html
```

But file remains unchanged.

Comment: if the `td` tags are all on same line, `sed -E 's/(.*<td[^>]*>)455(.*)/\164\2/'` .. now or later, you'll likely run into more issues.. use html parser instead or programming language with one..

Answer (score 0):

Before sed can parse your script, your shell will mess up the single quotes. Try to echo your script to see what happens.

In those cases I prefer to replace the quotes by a `.` in the matching pattern. This will work for real-world cases.

Then I'm not sure what your trailing `/g` is supposed to do. This will be part of the replacement, which you don't want. Why not simply do

```
sed -i '/<th width=.25%.><div class="detail"><b>VM Capacity<\/b><\/div><\/th>/!b;n;s/455/64/' cluster_report.html
```